# Deploying new versions of an image instantly

Tags: docker

I would like to have 3 versions of my container running at any one time (on the same machine). Something like this:

- version v7  (stage)
- version v6  (live)
- version v5  (old)

then I would like to map this to 3 urls:

- v7.example.com
- v6.example.com
- v5.example.com

And also, a 4th url, which refers to the current (or default) version:

www.example.com (which maps to http://**v6**.mydomain.com)

Presumably, I could take some configuration step that would change the "default" version from v6 to v7. That step should hopefully be instant and atomic.

The idea is that deploying the next version of an app is a distinct step from *activating* that version (by activate, I mean making that version the default).

Therefore a rollout (or a rollback) would simply be a matter of changing the default version to the next (or previous) version.

Google App Engine supports this kind of pattern and I really like it.

Has anyone set something like this up using Docker? I would appreciate any advice on how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a reverse proxy in front of the containers running your webapp.

### Example using the [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) image

Let's say your docker host IP address is `11.22.33.44`.

Let's say your docker images are:

- `mywebapp:5` for v5
- `mywebapp:6` for v6
- `mywebapp:7` for v7

First, make sure your DNS is set up so that `v5.example.com`, `v6.example.com`, `v7.example.com` and `www.example.com` all resolve to `11.22.33.44`.

Start a *jwilder/nginx-proxy* on your docker host:

```
docker run -d --name reverseproxy -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro -e DEFAULT_HOST=www.example.com jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

#### Set v6 as the default one

Start the webapps containers:

```
docker run -d -name webapp5 -e VIRTUAL_HOST="v5.example.com" mywebapp:5
docker run -d -name webapp6 -e VIRTUAL_HOST="v6.example.com,www.example.com" mywebapp:6
docker run -d -name webapp7 -e VIRTUAL_HOST="v7.example.com" mywebapp:7
```

The *jwilder/nginx-proxy* will use the value of the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable to update its configuration and route the requests to the correct container.

#### How to make v7 the new default one

First, remove container `webapp7` and create a new one with `www.example.com` added to the `VIRTUAL_HOST` variable:

```
docker rm webapp7
docker run -d -name webapp7 -e VIRTUAL_HOST="v7.example.com,www.example.com" mywebapp:7
```

In this state, the reverse proxy will load balance queries for `www.example.com` to both `webapp6` and `webapp7` containers.

Finally, remove container `webapp6` and eventually recreate it, but without `www.example.com` in the `VIRTUAL_HOST` value:

```
docker rm webapp6
docker run -d -name webapp6 -e VIRTUAL_HOST="v6.example.com" mywebapp:7
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share what I ended up doing. I took Thomasleveil's advice to use nginx. But rather than starting and stopping a whole docker container and nginx just to switch versions, I do this:

1. Change the port number in the nginx config file (see file below)
2. Call service nginx reload (which is instant).

```
server{
    location / {     
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.50:81/;
    }
}
```